# radio buttons on click template

Tags: html

Hello i need to know how i can give an on-click function for a radio buttons. I need that a specific type of text box appear when i click on radio buttons. I try lots of code and nothing work

the radio buttons code is :

```
    <html>
     <p>Choose your strategy:</p>
     <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="radio" name="choice-strategy" id="choice-strategy-long" checked>
      <label for="choice-strategy-long">Long</label>
       <div class="reveal-if-active">
       <label for="which-inputs">Good call. What's the name of your favorite dog?</label>
       <input type="text" id="which-inputs" name="which-inputs" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#choice-strategy-long">
       </div>

      <input type="radio" name="choice-strategy" id="choice-strategy-short">
      <label for="choice-strategy-short">Short</label>
       <div class="reveal-if-active">
      <input type="radio" name="choice-strategy" id="choice-strategy-longshort">
      <label for="choice-strategy-longshort">Long and Short</label>
       <div class="reveal-if-active">
 </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Do You Want to show another Textbox When Clicked on each radio button?

Comment: yes this is what i want

Comment: If Short is clicked. Then a text box below it and hide the Old One Is It?

Comment: yes exactly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You May Try This.

```
    <html>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
     <p>Choose your strategy:</p>
     <form action="" method="post" id="formid">
     <div>
      <input type="radio" name="choice-strategy" id="long" checked>
      <label for="choice-strategy-long">Long</label>
           <div class="long each_text">
                <label for="which-inputs">Good call. What's the name of your favorite dog?</label>
                <input type="text" id="which-inputs" name="long" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#choice-strategy-long">
           </div>
      </div>

      <div>
      <input type="radio" name="choice-strategy" id="short">
      <label for="choice-strategy-short">Short</label>
          <div class="hidden short each_text">
                <label for="which-inputs">Short</label>
                <input type="text" id="which-inputs" name="short" class="require-if-active " data-require-pair="#choice-strategy-long">
          </div>
       </div>

       <div>
      <input type="radio" name="choice-strategy" id="longshort">
      <label for="choice-strategy-longshort">Long and Short</label>
          <div class="hidden longshort each_text">
                <label for="which-inputs">Long and Short?</label>
                <input type="text" id="which-inputs" name="longshort" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#choice-strategy-long">
           </div>
    </div>
 </form>


 <script type="text/javascript">
$('#formid input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    $('.each_text').addClass('hidden');
    $('.each_text input').val('');
    var tovisible = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.'+tovisible).removeClass('hidden');

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .hidden{
        display: none;
    }
</style>


</html>
```

Comment: thank you !! and if it is a table ? I will show you a code related to a table

Comment: <fieldset>

 <h2> Stock Selection Criteria </h2>

    <p><strong>On the trading day </strong></p><hr>

    <table>

     <tr id="input_1">

      <td>1. Price (min, max)  <a data-toggle="popover" data-content="

<img src='{{STATIC_URL}}img/tutorial/documentation/img10.png'class='img-responsive img-rounded'/>

    "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

   </td>

      <td>{{ form.price_1_min.errors }}{{ form.price_1_min }} {{ form.price_1_max.errors }}{{ form.price_1_max }}</td>

     </tr>

Comment: i mean if it is a type of fieldset with table

Comment: Use the same idea.